# How to calculate $(k^x)^{-1} \pmod m$

Tags: exponentiation

I'm trying to follow [this example of ElGamal's encryption scheme](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~gts/268/lec9.pdf) (page 2, slides 3 & 4), but don't understand this step (decryption, step 2):

$$(k^x)^{-1} \pmod m$$
Where
$$k = 10,\ x = 9,\ m = 13$$

The slide shows that it becomes $$12^{-1} \pmod{13}= 12$$

Where did 12 come from? Also, can you help me see how the above equals 12?

I calculate:$$12^{-1} = \frac{1}{12}$$

Comment: You are supposed to work with congruences (and/or residue classes). Because
$$12\cdot12=144\equiv1\pmod{13}$$
$12$ is equal to its own inverse
in the group of units of the residue class ring $\mathbf{Z}_{13}$. This is even easier to see from the congruence
$$12\equiv -1\pmod{13}.$$
Surely $-1$ is equal to its reciprocal.

Comment: Okay, I will try to think about what you said. Is the reason why $k^{x}$ became 12 also explained in your comment?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you were also asking about $10^9$. Because $1001$ is divisible by $13$, we have
$$10^3=1000\equiv-1\pmod{13}.$$
Therefore we also have
$$10^9=(10^3)^3\equiv(-1)^3=-1\equiv 12\pmod{13}.$$
Moral: do not attempt El Gamal (or RSA) unless you are familiar with the arithmetic of congruences and residue classes.

Comment: Haha, duly noted. I have no idea why you chose 1001. Is there an another way to solve this without knowing about congruence arithmetic?

Comment: You could have just got your answer chatting with people. Anyways, you got a quick answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over the rationals, $\mathbb{Q},$ we have
$$ 12^{-1} = \frac{1}{12}$$
but over the *integers modulo $13,$* $\mathbb{Z}_{13},$ we have
$$ 12^{-1} \equiv x \pmod{13}$$
were $x$ is the [multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of $12$ modulo $13.$
To find $x,$ follow this argument. Since $$12^{-1} \equiv x \pmod{13},$$ we have $$12a \equiv 1 \pmod{13}.$$ Recall $1 \pmod{13} = 1 + 13k$ for some integer $k.$ So
$ 12x = 1 + 13k .$ Rearrange,
$$ 12x - 13k = 1.$$
This is similar to what the [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse#Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) gives us:
$$ 12x + 13k = \gcd(12, 13).$$
So compute the extended Euclidean algorithm on $12, 13$ you will get $12$ as the inverse (here is [one nice online calculator](http://2000clicks.com/mathhelp/NumberChineseExtendedEuclideanAlgorithm.aspx) and [another one](http://www.asakusuma.com/euclidean/euclidean.php); both perform extended GCD).

---

Another method is to construct the [multiplication table module $13$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=multiplication+table+modulo+13) and look for an entry $x$ such that $$ 12x \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$$

Comment: Whoever downvotes should be nice and give *constructive* criticism!

Answer (score 2):

Mod $13\!:\ 10\equiv -3\:$ so $\rm\: 10^9 \equiv ((-3)^3)^3\equiv (-27)^3\equiv (-1)^3\equiv -1,\:$ and $\rm\:(-1)^{-1}\equiv -1\equiv 12$

As above, generally modular arithmetic is easier using the least residue reps $\:0,\pm1,\pm2,\ldots, \pm6\:$ versus $\:0,1,2,\ldots 12\:$ modulo $13$.